# Make particles go to the target object and stick to it

Tags: particles

Is there any way to make particles move from one object(emitter) to another object and stick to it?

Answer (score 15):

You can use keyed particle system to do that. This is often used to morph an object shape (as particles) to another object shape.

[image]

The principle is to set up a particle system (PS) on a first object, then define a second one using the same PS (and eventually a third one, etc.).

For these PS you may set there physics to "No" (as if not, they will fall or move or other).

Now create another object, with a PS (a new one) and having the same amount of particles.

Go to the key section below. And set the (keyed steps you want for it). These steps are based on the previous PS, as they are defined.

- The key objects PS definition :

1- Start and end set to 1 (we want them all now)

2- Lifetime depending on what you want

3- Set to faces or volume (you choose)

4- No physics (if physics, that will work too, but theses PS will move)

You can use the same PS for the 3 (or 2 if you want 2) transition objects where particles are transiting above.

[image]

- The keyed PS

1- Define start, end and lifetime as you need

2- Set physics to 'Key'

3- Add 3 (or 2...) steps in the key using the '+' button

4- For each step assign the wanted key object

[image]

You can tune the time (check 'use timing') so that the PS leaves or stays (stuck) more or less a long time from an object to another :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Аs I understand when it comes to Keyed Physics, than normal force fields stop working? For example if I want to add some turbulence to the movement of the particles?

Comment: @IvanLebedev, you can enable physics on the key fields and that will have impact on the directed field

Comment: Big thanks for your help!!!

Another question

I have object A and object B.
Particles are have spiral movement in the direction from A to B by wind and vortex forces.

I need these particles to born another particles in some frame range. These second particles need to attack object B and stick to it.

Comment: @IvanLebedev, you may ask another question about that. It is better for BSE and that will allow you to ask your question more clearly than in the comments. Thanks