# Reverse explosion with voxels

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, volumetrics, sverchok

What I have: an array of vertices obtained through a simple Sverchok node that states the position of each voxel(many thousands of them).

[image]

What I would like to do is to create a reverse explosion effect, where the voxels(in the shape of cubes), that at the beginning are scattered in space, start to head towards the center one after another, until they have formed the bunny.

What I've managed to do so far is this, using particles systems, but it's not exactly that effect that I would like, since here the particles are moving all at the same time, whereas what I want is them to move one after another (more or less).

[image]

I'm new to animation, could this be done in a not too complicated way?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62209/make-particles-go-to-the-target-object-and-stick-to-it/62213#62213. Possible usage here: starting from a sphere surrounding the bunny and target to the bunny

Comment: @lemon I've updated my question in response to your comment

Comment: Have you tried to change start/end parameters of the PS first key (the sphere)?

Comment: From the previous comment, you can have this kind of effect https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcy71.gif. Is that it ?

Comment: Well, it would be a close enough probably:) I have tried now to do as you said but if I change the start/end parameters of the sphere it looks like nothing changes.. only if I change the ones of the controller I get some funky effects, but not the one that I want or that you've showed.. how did you setup the the different timings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

From this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62209/make-particles-go-to-the-target-object-and-stick-to-it/62213#62213), I've changed or set the following:

[image]

1- Keyed object
2- Particle
3- Surrounding sphere (viewed as bounds)
4- Bunny (viewed as bounds)

On the right the setting for keyed object (the 2nd PS has 10 for the time parameter).

[image]

Above the setting for the surrounding sphere (250 for the 'end' parameter).

And below the setting for the bunny:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, now it's much better, thanks! [link](http://imgur.com/a/KdFOU) One last thing though: now the particles are accumulating along the X axis, could I have them along the Z, or even better from the center? I am using vertex group for the bunny and I have tried to use Sort Mesh Elements, like for the Build Modifier, but it didn't work

Comment: @Alberto89, about this axis aspect, how did you get that along the X axis?

Comment: Not sure, removing the Random tick on the bunny seams to do the trick.. here's the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3107" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3107/)

Comment: Oh yes, the trick is to reorganize the vertex indices. Now the particles can grow from the center or on any axes direction. Thanks for the help. [link](http://imgur.com/4Ke7OaD)