# Is there a way to force particles to follow a branched object?

Tags: particles, path

I would like to make a particle system to flow through a branched object such as a tree or a light bolt. Forcing a particle system to flow through a path (e.g. Bezier Curve) is trivial using it as a force field if `type:Curve Guide` but since curves are categorically not branched it is not possible.

I have tried using a branched mesh to achieve the same results using the same recipe of `Force Field>Curve Guide` but the results are not the expected ones.

How would you go about it?

UPDATE:
This is one solution based on @lemon 's approach by using keyed particle systems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hySKQ.jpg

Comment: Have you tried using a keyed PS?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: In physics part, choose 'keyed', then you can indicate where the PS pass through in the relation part below. You can have this kind of things https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVa2X.gif. Each stage is a separate object having the same PS

Comment: An old answer about that (but still working) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62209/make-particles-go-to-the-target-object-and-stick-to-it/62213#62213

Comment: Gotcha! The idea is to make the path myself by using intermediate objects as key points instead of a path itself! Thanks I will try it now.

Comment: Hey, BTW you can have curves that branch, just select the curve handles, press **v** and select vector, and you'll have a jagged path.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it is very useful for jagged paths but it is still a single path, right, handle can't bi- or tri-furcate, right?