# blender transform between three words

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to do a text (mesh) explode where I go from the words 
"Line1" to "Line2" to Line3 with particle physics.

The line1 to line2 works great, but in going from line2 to line3, the word line2 remains, see image below.

in the image is the particale setting.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have 3 texts, probably you need 3 lines in the keys in PS.

Comment: The problem is in picture 3 and 6 line2 is still seen.

Comment: Hard to see clearly in the screen caps.. same PS for the 3? Can that help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62209/make-particles-go-to-the-target-object-and-stick-to-it/62213#62213 ?

Comment: Got it to work, using the timinig and slider, but donot know exactly how the slider work

Comment: see comment above. use the the timing but don't understand the setting.