# co-ordinates while morph particles into shapes

Tags: particles

is it possible to export to csv etc. of x, y, z coordinate and colour of each particle in each frame doing morph particles into shapes like in video below?
https://youtu.be/UgmJsLcLXUI?t=639

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62213/19156

Comment: He's likely using keyed particle systems. Finicky to set up, but it works. You can get the particles' positions, however you don't have access to the particles' colors. He's just transitioning between colors though, so you could just arbitrarily add them over time using the same method you use to colorize the material.